# Setting MenuItem icon through style setter

Tags: wpf, xaml, menuitem

```
<Style x:Key="ContextMenuItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{Binding Icon}" />
    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Text}" />
    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Children}" />
    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}" />
</Style>
```

setting it in code like this:

```
Uri refreshUri = new Uri("..\\Resources\\Refresh16.bmp",UriKind.Relative);
BitmapImage refreshIcon = new BitmapImage();
refreshIcon.UriSource = refreshUri;
```

the Icon doesn't show up, any clues ?

Answer (score 8):

If the `refreshIcon` is the source of your `Icon` property, then you may need to either call `NotifyPropertyChanged("Icon")` after your code example (and implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface) and/or declare `Icon` as a `DependencyProperty`.

Here is a link to more information about the [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface.

Ahh, I see your problem... try setting the `Icon` property to an `Image` and bind to the source of the `Image`:

```
<Setter Property="Icon">
    <Setter.Value>
        <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" />
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

You can also just put the image into an Images folder in your main project and reference it in xaml like this:

```
<Setter Property="Icon">
    <Setter.Value>
        <Image Source="/ProjectName;component/Images/IconName.ico" />
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Comment: my context menu shows this: 
[System.Windows.media.Imaging.BitmapImage  Refresh]

Answer (score 7):

For anyone still looking for a solution, this worked for me:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Image x:Key="Icon" Source="/ProjectName;component/Images/IconName.ico" x:Shared="false"/>
    <Style x:Key="MenuItem">
        <Setter Property="MenuItem.Header" Value="Header Text"/>
        <Setter Property="MenuItem.Icon" Value="{DynamicResource Icon}"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```